# ejabberd: How to use "ldap_tls_certfile"

Tags: ejabberd

According to the [ejabberd docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/toplevel/#ldap-tls-certfile), you can use **ldap_tls_certfile** in order to verify the TLS connection to the LDAP server. But which certificate is expected here?

Quoting the docs:

> A path to a file containing PEM encoded certificate along with PEM
> encoded private key. This certificate will be provided by ejabberd
> when TLS enabled for LDAP connections. There is no default value,
> which means no client certificate will be sent.

Sooo.... I tried to use a concatenated PEM file containing first the host certificate of the ejabberd server, then second the host key. But this leads to the following errors:

> <0.471.0>@eldap:connect_bind:1073 LDAP connection to
> ldap1.example.com:636 failed: received CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Handshake
> Failure - {bad_cert,hostname_check_failed}
>
> <0.1975.0> TLS client: In state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:1372 generated CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Handshake Failure - {bad_cert,hostname_check_failed}

This obviously is not what is expected. Is it the public certificate of the LDAP server? But then, what private key is expected?

I'm a bit lost here. Anyone mind to lend me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I never used LDAP TLS.

Looking at the ejabberd source code, the value of ejabberd's option ldap_tls_certfile
is copied into eldap's option tls_certfile
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/e4d600729396a8539e48ac0cbd97ea1b210941cd/include/eldap.hrl#L72

And later the value of eldap's tls_certfile is copied into ssl's option certfile
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/e4d600729396a8539e48ac0cbd97ea1b210941cd/src/eldap.erl#L580

That option, among others, is provided as an argument when calling ssl:connect/4
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/e4d600729396a8539e48ac0cbd97ea1b210941cd/src/eldap.erl#L1140

So, the option that you set in ejabberd is named 'certfile' in ssl:connect, you can see here its documentation:
https://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#connect-4

Searching for **certfile** in that page, it shows this description:

```
Path to a file containing the user certificate on PEM format.
```

> Is it the public certificate of the LDAP server?

Try that one and comment here.

> But then, what private key is expected?

Try not putting any private key. In any case, when the LDAP certificate was created, it produced a private key file, too.

Comment: Nice deduction!

Okay, so I tried using just the PEM certificate of the ldap server here. It complains about a missing key:

`2020-10-09 11:50:49.979 [error] <0.466.0>@eldap:connect_bind:1073 LDAP connection to ldap1.example.com:636 failed: Invalid key file /opt/ejabberd/conf/certs/im.example.com.pem: decoding error`

Even using the full certificate chain (we're using intermediate certificates) results in the same output.

The certificate does have the correct file permissions of course:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 ejabberd ejabberd 1944 Okt  9 11:50 /opt/ejabberd/conf/certs/im.example.com.pem`

Comment: Okay, what about using the host certificate of the ejabberd host along with the private key?

`2020-10-09 11:54:37.646 [error] <0.466.0>@eldap:connect_bind:1073 LDAP connection to ldap1.example.com:636 failed: received CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Handshake Failure - {bad_cert,hostname_check_failed}`
`2020-10-09 11:54:37.646 [info] <0.951.0> TLS client: In state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:1372 generated CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Handshake Failure - {bad_cert,hostname_check_failed}`

Using the full certificate chain results in the same output.

Comment: I have to add that host certificates use a different intermediate cert than tls certificates. But all use the same root ca, of course.

Comment: Okay, so i created a dedicated TLS certificate. What about using that one?

`2020-10-09 12:00:22.272 [error] <0.469.0>@eldap:connect_bind:1073 LDAP connection to ldap1.example.com:636 failed: received CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Handshake Failure - {bad_cert,hostname_check_failed}`
`2020-10-09 12:00:22.272 [info] <0.988.0> TLS client: In state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:1372 generated CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Handshake Failure - {bad_cert,hostname_check_failed}`

No dice, either.